# Only copy data from Worksheet if name conforms to YYYY-MM format

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to consolidate data from several files and worksheets  (11 Files, ~50 worksheets in each of them).
Copying the data into a different sheet works fine, but I would like to only read/copy data from a Worksheet that conforms to the format "YYYY-MM" and none with different names (such as table1, etc..).

I know that the name of the worksheet is a string, but how do i get it to conform to the requirements?
I considered using `len(7)` but this would also include any string that has 7 characters.

Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: And how are you going about doing this? Formula? VBA? Based on what you wrote I can only suggest to check if the "string/substrings" are values (perhaps between certain numbers, like month needs to be between 1 and 12).

Comment: You will need to have a clear understanding of how the cell format YYYY-MM came about.  The data in the cell could be the text string 2022-09, or it could be the date serial number (which today would be 44,805) with a YYYY-MM format applied to it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by having a formula obtain the tab name, then see if a date can be made from it by adding to it "-01" and using that as an input to `DATEVALUE`, then using `TEXT` to change that result to a "YYYY-MM" form and comparing that result to the tab name you obtained.

Sounds like a lot, but the following does it and isn't very involved:

```
=LET(TabName,  RIGHT(CELL("filename",'2022-05'!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",'2022-05'!A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",'2022-05'!A1))),

 IF(TabName=TEXT(DATEVALUE(TabName&"-01"),"YYYY-MM"),TRUE,FALSE)
 )
```

`CELL` is the function that obtains the tab name. It produces a file path and name plus the sheet name. I used "old school" `FIND`, etc., to cut out all but the actual sheet name which conveniently starts after the only "]" character in the string. (One uses the `LEN` of that full string minus that position to get the actual sheet name.)

If you have the newest text functions Excel offers, a simple `TEXTAFTER` would do it in one small bit of formula.

I used `LET` as most seem to have that now and you didn't indicate a need for older versions to be accommodated. But one can just copy the value of "TabName" and paste it in to remove `LET` if need be or preferred.

So then concatenate the string TabName with "-01" so if it IS in the right form, it will be a valid date. Use that in `DATEVALUE` to return a... date value... for the string (note, it may have already failed if the name were, say, "Sheeet1" but you don't mind where it fails, if it does, so...). Return that date back into a text string with one of the functions that do so, like `TEXT` but in the format of "YYYY-MM" and then do a simple `IF` test to see if it matches the TabName or does not.

I gave the formula a simple TRUE/FALSE output, but you would substitute whatever you like for either or both. The only thing addressed here was defining whether or not the sheet name is in the acceptable/desired form.